# Problem with simple guessing game in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a simple guessing game in JavaScript, but when I click submit button - nothing happens. This is a code from a book, so I think it should work. Do you have any idea what is wrong with it?

Below is the HTML and JS code. I have this two files in one folder.

I would be greatful for any ideas.

```js
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;

const guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
const lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
const lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');

const guessSubmit = document.querySelector('guessSubmit');
const guessField = document.querySelector('guessField');

let guessCount = 1;
let resetButton;

function checkGuess() {
  var userGuess = Number(guessField.value);
  if (guessCount === 1) {
    guesses.textContent = 'Poprzednio wprowadzone liczby: ';
  }
  guesses.textContent += userGuess + ' ';

  if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Gratulacje! Zgadłeś!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    lowOrHi.textContent = '';
    setGameOver();
  } else if (guessCount === 10) {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Koniec gry!';
    setGameOver();
  } else {
    lastResult.textContent = 'Żle!';
    lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    if (userGuess < randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Zbyt mała liczba!';
    } else if (userGuess > randomNumber) {
      lowOrHi.textContent = 'Zbyt duża liczba!';
    }
  }

  guessCount++;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();
}

guessSubmit.addEventListener('click', checkGuess);

function setGameOver() {
  guessField.disabled = true;
  guessSubmit.disabled = true;
  resetButton = document.createElement('button');
  resetButton.textContent = 'Rozpocznij nową grę!';
  document.body.appendChild(resetButton);
  resetButton.addEventListener('click', resetGame);
}

function resetGame() {
  guessCount = 1;

  var resetParas = document.querySelectorAll('.resultParas p');
  for (var i = 0; i < resetParas.length; i++) {
    resetParas[i].textContent = '';
  }

  resetButton.parentNode.removeChild(resetButton);

  guessField.disabled = false;
  guessSubmit.disabled = false;
  guessField.value = '';
  guessField.focus();

  lastResult.style.backgroundColor = 'white';

  randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 480px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.lastResult {
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Zgadnij liczbę</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Zgadnij liczbę</h1>
  <p>Program wybrał liczbę od 1 do 100. Sprawdź, czy uda Ci się ją odgadnąć w mniej niż 10 prób. Otrzymasz odpowiedzi, czy zgadywana przez Ciebie wartość jest zbyt duża lub zbyt mała.</p>
  <div class="form">
    <label for="guessField">Wprowadź liczbę: </label>
    <input type="text" id="guessField" class="guessField">
    <input type="submit" value="Wyślij odpowiedź" class="guessSubmit">
  </div>
  <div class="resultParas">
    <p class="guesses"></p>
    <p class="lastResult"></p>
    <p class="lowOrHi"></p>
  </div>
  <<script src="zgadywanie.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You forgot the `.` before the class name in `document.querySelector('.guessSubmit')` and `document.querySelector('guessField')`

Comment: @Barmar wow you're right! Thank you! Details are important :)

Comment: In your JavaScript, `querySelector('guessSubmit')` should probably be `querySelector('.guessSubmit')` since `guessSubmit` is a class. Same with your `guessField` variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get elements by [type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors) selector, but in HTML you haven't these types. Instead, try [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) selector.

```
const guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
const guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');
```

Comment: I'd just add that if you know the class you should probably use .getElementsByClassName, better performance